# How for loop work with JavaScript EventListner

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addeventlistener

I have a html document where has 3 button and one h1 element. I have tried to  change the h1 element content by clicking in each button with **EventListene**r. And i have done this too. But i dont understand how **foor loop** work there. **How exact button working when i am click on them?**

```js
//JavaScript Code
var len = document.querySelectorAll(".mybutton").length

for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var doucemnts = document.querySelectorAll("button")[i]
    doucemnts.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var text = this.innerHTML
        document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML=  "You Have Selected " + text
        console.log(i)
       
    })
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>You have selected no button</h1>
    
    <button class="mybutton">Button 1</button>
    <button class="mybutton">Button 2</button>
    <button class="mybutton">Button 3</button>

    <script src="index.js">
      

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Can Anyone Tell me How For loop worked there?**

Comment: It's really a trivial code maybe the variable names are a little confusing and the loop is inefficient. But basically it sets event listener **for** every button

Answer (score 0):

In JS when manipulating DOM elements, it's better to query elements once at start of your code then reuse those variables. Another important thing to consider is to use `const`/`let` instead of old `var` keyword. Here's your updated code based on that and might make more sense now:

```js
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.mybutton');

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    const text = this.innerHTML;
    h1.innerHTML = "You Have Selected " + text;
  });
}
```

This code is basically doing the same, but instead of querying for elements on each iteration, it's done once before starting loop. Then loop over the buttons one by one and add click event to each one of them.

You can also use `for..of` it might be easier to understand. Here's the code updated to use `for..of`:

```js
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.mybutton');
for (const button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const text = this.innerHTML;
    h1.innerHTML = 'You Have Selected ' + text;
  });
}
```

**Update:** The main thing to understand in both code snippets is `const text = this.innerHTML`. This line of code is using the `this` keyword to get the HTML content of each button. `this` keyword will be pointing to button triggered the event, so based on that you're getting text displayed on that button using `innerHTML` property and concatenate that to content of h1. In short, getting text in clicked button and append to h1 content.

I have removed `console.log(i)` as it refers to variable `i` that is valid only while add the event listener callback only. It'll show an error because when event callback function is called there will be no for loop and i won't be defined.

Comment: Tell me more about for loop please. Still i am strugling to understand how for loop give the exact number when i am clicking on the button

Comment: I've updated my answer to include more explanation about the loop and how `h1` is set

Answer (score 0):

For in [the nodelist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) attach [an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) that calls a function when the button is clicked. The function updates the `h1` with the button text.

Your code can be improved slightly by caching all the elements up front, and then using those references in [the loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement) (a for/of loop is a little easier to parse) instead.

```js
// Cache the elements
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.mybutton');
const heading = document.querySelector('h1');

// Loop over `buttons`
for (const button of buttons) {

  // For every button add a click listener
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {

    // Assign the button textContent to a new variable
    const text = this.textContent;

    // Use that variable to update the textContent
    // of the heading textContent
    heading.textContent = 'You Have Selected ' + text;
  });
}
```

```html
<h1>You Have Selected No Button</h1>
<button class="mybutton">Button 1</button>
<button class="mybutton">Button 2</button>
<button class="mybutton">Button 3</button>
```

You could even use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/). It attaches *one* listener to a parent element which captures events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM.

```js
// Cache the elements, and a partial string 
const heading = document.querySelector('h1');
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
const tmpl = 'You Have Selected';

// Add an event listener to the buttons container
buttons.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {

  // If the child element that fired the
  // click event is a button
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    
    // Construct the new string, and assign it
    // to the heading textContent
    const text = `${tmpl} ${e.target.textContent}`;
    heading.textContent = text;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>You Have Selected No Button</h1>
<section class="buttons">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 3</button>
</section>
```

Additional information

- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: still i dont get the point how for loof worked there. when i click on the button 2. how "i" contain 2? why its not contain 0?

Comment: `i` is the _index_ of the button in the loop's current iteration. The function gets the text content of that button ("Button 2") and assigns it to the text content of the heading. @KHSHAKIB. You should look at [the documentation for loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).